# How to get parent class in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have a `StudentDashboard.java` which contains multiple `Student.java` panels(rows). In each row, I have an ellipsis which pops-up `OptionMenu.java`(panel).

In `OptionMenu.java`, I have a remove link which deletes a student from the Db, so on UI, I also want to remove corresponding `Student.java` panel(row) from the dashboard.

The delete logic is in `OptionMenu.java`. How can I get corresponding `Student.java` reference in `OptionMenu.java`? So that I can do something like `student.removeFromParent()`.

**Whether delete method should be part of OptionMenu or Student class?**

Answer (score 0):

If your Studen.java inherit vom the GWT Panel. you can use getParent() which will return the parent Widget that your Studen is attached to.